# detect process that executes portscans

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp, debugging, scanner

I have to administer an ubuntu 12.04 server, where there seem to go portscans to the whole subnet. How can I find out the process that does the scans?

```
pstree
init─┬─acpid
     ├─apache2───14*[apache2]
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─colord───2*[{colord}]
     ├─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-dae}]
     ├─cron
     ├─cupsd
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─fail2ban-server───2*[{fail2ban-server}]
     ├─gam_server
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─kdm─┬─Xorg
     │     └─kdm───kdm_greet───2*[{kdm_greet}]
     ├─mysqld───27*[{mysqld}]
     ├─ntpd
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─smbd───smbd
     ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───su───bash───tmux
     ├─tmux───bash───pstree
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     ├─upstart-socket-
     └─upstart-udev-br
```

Comment: Have you looked at `netstat`?

Comment: this is the output of netstat: http://pastebin.com/vScNcz99

Comment: @rubo77 `netstat -nap`

Comment: netstat -nap: http://pastebin.com/AUdWDSv2

Comment: @rubo77 probably you'd like to exclude port listening daemons and other known software: 
`netstat -nat4p | egrep -v -E "LISTEN|nmbd|smbd|apache2|mysqld|cupsd|sshd|ntpd|avahi-daemon"`; also it's obvious that your port scanner is triggered by cron, so it's useful to check it as well.

Comment: then there is not much left: http://pastebin.com/bUM2PFNz . how can I check cron as well? What exactly could I check there?

Answer (score 0):

use lsof.  It shows processes and their associated files.  For you, you should look for IP (implying sockets) instead of regular files.  This should tell you which process is doing the scan.  Then you can track how the process is called.